# MTG for android: In-App buy valid for other devices as well? (same google account)

Tags: android, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2014

Magic The Gathering for android: If i buy "in app" full game, will it be unlocked in every devices i use for the time being or just the one where i did the upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game will be available on every device connected with the same google account, if you try to buy it twice it will say "you already own this item". However you must reinstall the game any other devices where you didn't purchase the game. The game run well on phones too you just have to copy the apk file, the full version will unlock itself on the first startup.